# Converting a MatchCollection to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

Is there a better way than this to convert a MatchCollection to a string array?

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b");
string[] strArray = new string[mc.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count;i++ )
{
    strArray[i] = mc[i].Groups[0].Value;
}
```

P.S.: `mc.CopyTo(strArray,0)` throws an exception:

> At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Try:

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I would have used `OfType<Match>()` for this instead of `Cast<Match>()` ... Then again, the outcome would be the same.

Comment: @Alex You know that everything returned will be a `Match`, so there's no need to check it again at runtime.  `Cast` makes more sense.

Comment: @DaveBish I posted some sort-of benchmarking code below, `OfType<>` turns out to be slightly faster.

Comment: @DaveBish: don't worry about OfType vs Cast performance. Your #1 performance dog is `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: for future visitors, this have been argued: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432268/187510

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this: var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
Since there aren't any parenthesis in the pattern I don't see a reason to use the Group property unless it doesn't do what I think it does.

Comment: @Frontenderman - Nope, I was just aligning it with the askers question

Comment: You would think it would be a simple command to turn a `MatchCollection` into a `string[]`, as it is for `Match.ToString()`. It's pretty obvious the final type needed  in a lot of `Regex` uses would be a string, so it should have been easy to convert.

Comment: @n00dles I agree, though the first annoying thing is having to deal with a non-generic ICollection and IEnumerable type, though to be totally fair, I'm pretty sure this API was made prior even to generic C# support.

Answer (score 33):

Dave Bish's answer is good and works properly.

It's worth noting although that replacing `Cast<Match>()` with `OfType<Match>()` will speed things up.

Code wold become:

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Result is exactly the same (and addresses OP's issue the exact same way) but for huge strings it's faster.

Test code:

```
// put it in a console application
static void Test()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string strText = "this will become a very long string after my code has done appending it to the stringbuilder ";

    Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).ToList().ForEach(i => sb.Append(strText));
    strText = sb.ToString();

    sw.Start();
    var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
              .OfType<Match>()
              .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
              .ToArray();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("OfType: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();
    var arr2 = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
              .ToArray();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Cast: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

Output follows:

```
OfType: 6540
Cast: 8743
```

For *very long* strings Cast() is therefore slower.

Comment: Very surprising! Given that OfType must do an 'is' comparison somewhere inside and a cast (I'd have thought?) Any ideas on why Cast<> is slower? I've got nothing!

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue, but it "feels" right to me (OfType<> is just a filter, Cast<> is ... well, is a cast)

Comment: More benchmarks seem to show this particular result is due to regex more than specific linq extension used

Comment: I've written a more complex benchmark that hopefully answers this once and for all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77842454/285678

Answer (score 6):

I ran the exact same benchmark that Alex has posted and found that sometimes `Cast` was faster and sometimes `OfType` was faster, but the difference between both was negligible. However, while ugly, the for loop is consistently faster than both of the other two.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string strText = "this will become a very long string after my code has done appending it to the stringbuilder ";
Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).ToList().ForEach(i => sb.Append(strText));
strText = sb.ToString();

//First two benchmarks

sw.Start();
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b");
var matches = new string[mc.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++)
{
    matches[i] = mc[i].ToString();
}
sw.Stop();
```

Results:

```
OfType: 3462
Cast: 3499
For: 2650
```

Comment: no surprise that linq is slower than for loop. Linq may be easier to write for some people and "increase" their productivity at the expense executing time. that can be good sometimes

Comment: So the original post is the most efficient method really.

Comment: I've written a more precise benchmark and it's not as clear cut as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77842454/285678

Answer (score 4):

One could also make use of this extension method to deal with the annoyance of `MatchCollection` not being generic. Not that it's a big deal, but this is almost certainly more performant than `OfType` or `Cast`, because it's just enumerating, which both of those also have to do.

(Side note: I wonder if it would be possible for the .NET team to make `MatchCollection` inherit generic versions of `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` in the future? Then we wouldn't need this extra step to immediately have LINQ transforms available).

```
public static IEnumerable<Match> ToEnumerable(this MatchCollection mc)
{
    if (mc != null) {
        foreach (Match m in mc)
            yield return m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since netcore3.0/netstandard2.1 the `IMatchCollection` class implements the generic `IEnumerable<Match>` interface (thanks Poul Bak for pointing that out). This makes `.Cast`/`.OfType` obsolete on these newer NET targets. I've wrapped it all in a neat extension method:

```
public static class RegexpExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> AsStrings(this MatchCollection matches)
#if NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER
        => matches.Select(m => m.ToString());
#else
        => matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.ToString());
#endif
}
```

I choose to return an `IEnumerable<string>` because enumerating the `MatchCollection` is lazily done, while calling `.ToArray` is an expensive way to populate the `MatchCollection` ([MatchCollection remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=net-8.0#remarks)). If you really need a string array simply chain a call to it: `matches.AsStrings().ToArray`.

The accepted answer is indeed pretty good and correct, but there's an open debate on what is faster: `OfType` or `Cast`, and starting with netcore 3.0 or netstandard 2.1 `MatchCollection` implements the generic `ICollection<Match>` interface which allows us to use `Select` without `.Cast`. People did some benchmarking, but all benchmarks I see were poorly done as they didn't use a proper tool for benchmarking, and included the `regex` run time in the results. So I decided to put the two approaches to the test with a properly done benchmark by using the amazing [BenchmarckDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). I've also included the memory diagnoser in the results to see if there's any difference in allocations and memory usage for each approach. Here are the results (with a netcore3.1+ version added for completeness):

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.12, Windows 10 (10.0.19045.3930/22H2/2022Update)
AMD Ryzen 7 5800X, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK 7.0.403
  [Host]     : .NET 7.0.13 (7.0.1323.51816), X64 RyuJIT AVX2 [AttachedDebugger]
  DefaultJob : .NET 7.0.13 (7.0.1323.51816), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
```

| Method | Mean | Error | Gen0 | Gen1 | Gen2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BenchSelect | 89.37 ms | 0.796 ms | 3500.0000 | 3333.3333 | 166.6667 | 67.9 MB |
| BenchCast | 89.72 ms | 1.132 ms | 3500.0000 | 3333.3333 | 166.6667 | 67.9 MB |
| BenchOfType | 120.70 ms | 1.069 ms | 3500.0000 | 3333.3333 | 166.6667 | 83.9 MB |
| BenchNet6 | 88.54 ms | 1.027 ms | 3500.0000 | 3333.3333 | 166.6667 | 67.9 MB |

These results are exactly what I expected: `Cast` is faster and uses less memory, and the difference in speed is negligible. `Cast` also allocates less memory than `OfType`. Also, netcore3.1+ version without `.Cast` is slightly faster, but nothing noticeable, and it changes between runs (since it's within the margin of error of the benchmark) with `BenchSelect` sometimes beating it.

The benchmark code follows (updated with the netcore3.1+ version):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<OfTypeVsCastBenchmark>();
//BenchmarkRunner.Run<ConvertMatchColletionToStringArrayBenchmarks>();

[HideColumns("matches")]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class OfTypeVsCastBenchmark
{
    public OfTypeVsCastBenchmark() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string strText = "this will become a very long string after my code has done appending it to the stringbuilder ";
        Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).ToList().ForEach(i => sb.Append(strText));
        Text = sb.ToString();
    }

    public string Text { get; }

    public IEnumerable<object> Matches() {
        yield return Regex.Matches(Text, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b");
    }

    [Benchmark, ArgumentsSource(nameof(Matches))]
    public string[] BenchSelect(MatchCollection matches) => matches
        .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.ToString()).ToArray();

    [Benchmark, ArgumentsSource(nameof(Matches))]
    public string[] BenchCast(MatchCollection matches) => matches
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.ToString())
        .ToArray();

    [Benchmark, ArgumentsSource(nameof(Matches))]
    public string[] BenchOfType(MatchCollection matches) => matches
          .OfType<Match>()
          .Select(m => m.ToString())
          .ToArray();

#if NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER
    [Benchmark, ArgumentsSource(nameof(Matches))]
    public string[] BenchNet6(MatchCollection matches) => matches
        .Select(m => m.ToString()).ToArray();
#endif
}
```

This answers once and for all which Linq-based solution is faster, which is `Cast`. But what is the fastest way to convert a `MatchCollection` to a `string[]`?

### Is foreach or for faster than Linq?

To see if using LINQ to convert `MatchColletion` into `string[]` is wasteful I've written two variants to compare:

```
public string[] ConvertByForEachIntoListThenToArray() {
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(Text))
        list.Add(match.Groups[0].Value);
    return list.ToArray();

}

public string[] ConvertByForEachIntoAllocatedArray() {
    var matches = regex.Matches(Text);
    var result = new string[matches.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        result[i] = matches[i].Groups[0].Value;
    return result;
}
```

Surprisingly using `for` or `foreach` to iterate over the `MatchCollection` and building the array manually is not noticeably faster than the more expressive LINQ version. The surprise for me is that using a `List<string>` then calling `ToArray()` on it is faster than preallocating the array and filling it. It happens because the `MatchCollection` is lazily evaluated when accessing its enumerator, but accessing `Count` will populate the collection which is expensive. Also NET 7 is noticeably faster than 4.7.1, so if you can then you should convert to NET 7!

Here are the results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.12, Windows 10 (10.0.19045.3930/22H2/2022Update)
AMD Ryzen 7 5800X, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK 7.0.403
  [Host]               : .NET 7.0.13 (7.0.1323.51816), X64 RyuJIT AVX2 [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET 7.0             : .NET 7.0.13 (7.0.1323.51816), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  .NET Framework 4.7.1 : .NET Framework 4.8.1 (4.8.9181.0), X64 RyuJIT VectorSize=256
```

| Method | Runtime | Mean | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ConvertByLinqWithCastToArray | .NET 7.0 | 796.9 ms | 501.97 MB |
| ConvertByForEachIntoListThenToArray | .NET 7.0 | 732.9 ms | 533.97 MB |
| ConvertByForEachIntoAllocatedArray | .NET 7.0 | 802.1 ms | 501.97 MB |
| ConvertByLinqWithCastToArray | .NET Framework 4.7.1 | 1,199.5 ms | 542.97 MB |
| ConvertByForEachIntoListThenToArray | .NET Framework 4.7.1 | 1,177.6 ms | 542.97 MB |
| ConvertByForEachIntoAllocatedArray | .NET Framework 4.7.1 | 1,224.8 ms | 510.98 MB |

And here is the class used for this specific benchmark:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net471)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net70)]
public class ConvertMatchColletionToStringArrayBenchmarks
{
    public ConvertMatchColletionToStringArrayBenchmarks() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string strText = "this will become a very long string after my code has done appending it to the stringbuilder ";
        Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).ToList().ForEach(i => sb.Append(strText));
        Text = sb.ToString();
    }

    public string Text { get; }

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    [Benchmark]
    public string[] ConvertByLinqWithCastToArray() => regex
        .Matches(Text)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
        .ToArray();
    [Benchmark]
    public string[] ConvertByForEachIntoListThenToArray() { 
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(Text))
            list.Add(match.Groups[0].Value);
        return list.ToArray();

    }
    [Benchmark]
    public string[] ConvertByForEachIntoAllocatedArray() {
        var matches = regex.Matches(Text);
        var result = new string[matches.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            result[i] = matches[i].Groups[0].Value;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your benchmark is not necessary anymore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=net-8.0

Comment: @PoulBak Why not?

Comment: `.Cast<Match>()`is not necessary.

Comment: @PoulBak Oh, I see. You're assuming all of us moved on to netcore3.0+ or netstandard2.1... If you're targeting netstandard2.0 (which most of my libraries do) or if you are stuck with a NET Framework app (which I'm since 2011 - a huge WebForms product I'm the maintainer) then this benchmark is somewhat useful (it's not much relevant because the difference in performance is negligible for the vast majority of use cases, but still interesting...). I'll add a version for NET6.0 to the benchmark for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code...

```
var emailAddress = "joe@sad.com; joe@happy.com; joe@elated.com";
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
emails = Regex.Matches(emailAddress, @"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: ugh... That regex is horrendous to look at. BTW, as there doesn't exist a foolproof regex for validating emails, use the MailAddress object. http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2437521

Answer (score 0):

If you need a recursive capture, eg. **Tokenizing Math Equations:**

```
//INPUT (I need this tokenized to do math)
    string sTests = "(1234+5678)/ (56.78-   1234   )";
            
    Regex splitter = new Regex(@"([\d,\.]+|\D)+");
    Match match = splitter.Match(sTests.Replace(" ", ""));
    string[] captures = (from capture in match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Last().Captures.Cast<Capture>()
                         select capture.Value).ToArray();
```

...because you need to go after the last captures in the last group.