# Why is OfType<> faster than Cast<>?

Tags: c#, linq

In answer to the following question:
[How to convert MatchCollection to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416191/how-to-convert-matchcollection-to-string-array/11416739#comment15078364_11416739)

Given The two Linq expressions:

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
    .OfType<Match>() //OfType
    .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

and

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(strText, @"\b[A-Za-z-']+\b")
    .Cast<Match>() //Cast
    .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

OfType<> was benchmarked by user [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999042/alex) to be slightly faster (and confirmed by myself).

This seems counterintuitive to me, as I'd have thought OfType<> would have to do both an 'is' comparison, *and* a cast (T).

Any enlightenment would be appreciated as to why this is the case :)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the question is not _what_ the difference is, but why one is slower than the other.

Comment: @danbystrom In [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015976/11683) to the question you linked to Ash explains `OfType` is slower. The OP asks why it's actually faster when all elements of the sequence are in fact of that type.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: This is not even a real question...

Comment: Why would it do `is` then a cast, when it can just use `as` and a null check?

Comment: I'm not sure! Which of those would be faster? - The question still holds, however...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't know. Maybe the Ash's answer is wrong. I only mention it because danbystrom linked to that question as a duplicate. **Which it is not, please stop voting for close.**

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Your answer lies here [Cast and OfType :yes Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx)

Comment: This question may be worth revisiting for C# 7 due to the `is` operator patterns? Though I suppose that depends on whether the methods have been kept up to date.

Comment: @V4Vendetta that link is broken. This is the new URL:
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My benchmarking does not agree with your benchmarking.

I ran an identical benchmark to Alex's and got the opposite result. I then tweaked the benchmark somewhat and again observed `Cast` being faster than `OfType`.

<strike>There's not much in it, but I believe that `Cast` does have the edge, as it should because its iterator is simpler. (No `is` check.)</strike>

<strike>Edit: Actually after some further tweaking I managed to get `Cast` to be 50x faster than `OfType`.</strike>

Below is the code of the benchmark that gives the biggest discrepancy I've found so far:

```
Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

var ma = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();

var x = ma.OfType<string>().ToArray();
var y = ma.Cast<string>().ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        sw1.Start();
        var arr = ma.OfType<string>().ToArray();
        sw1.Stop();
        sw2.Start();
        var arr2 = ma.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        sw2.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        sw2.Start();
        var arr2 = ma.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        sw2.Stop();
        sw1.Start();
        var arr = ma.OfType<string>().ToArray();
        sw1.Stop();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("OfType: " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Cast: " + sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Tweaks I've made:

- Perform the "generate a list of strings" work *once*, at the start, and "crystallize" it.
- Perform one of each operation before starting timing - I'm not sure if this is necessary but I think it means the JITter generates code beforehand rather than while we're timing?
- Perform each operation multiple times, not just once.
- Alternate the order in case this makes a difference.

*On my machine* this results in ~350ms for `Cast` and ~18000ms for `OfType`.

<strike>I think the biggest difference is that we're no longer timing how long `MatchCollection` takes to find the next match. (Or, in my code, how long `int.ToString()` takes.) This drastically reduces the signal-to-noise ratio.</strike>

Edit: As sixlettervariables pointed out, the reason for this massive difference is that `Cast` will short-circuit and not bother casting individual items if it can cast the whole `IEnumerable`. When I switched from using `Regex.Matches` to an array to avoid measuring the regex processing time, I also switched to using something castable to `IEnumerable<string>` and thus activated this short-circuiting. When I altered my benchmark to disable this short-circuiting, I get a ***slight*** advantage to `Cast` rather than a ***massive*** one.

Comment: @Alex Done. I don't think there are any gaping holes in my benchmark, but feel free to point them out if there are.

Comment: I start to believe the odd result I've seen is caused by the regex... I'm fiddling with some more and my results are now consistent with yours

Comment: @Rawling: Cast is faster in this case because it simply returns the enumeration unmolested because it implements `IEnumerable<string>`. Cast special cases.

Comment: @six ...buh. Of course. Now I remember why we were using `Regex.Matches` in the first place... I'll see if I can come up with a benchmark that will give me a useful result while still cutting out the work the regex is doing.

Comment: @Rawling: I've done so in my answer. There is no appreciable difference after random trials.

Comment: @six I've updated my answer to acknowledge and credit you for pointing this out. I still get a slight advantage to `Cast` but of course nothing like I was seeing before.

Comment: @Rawling - maybe `.ToArray()` is dominating the time measurement, as that requires allocating and filling a large array. Actually, since there is no way for it to predict the array size needed [it only knows that it has an IEnumerable, so no size available], it probably reallocates and copies the array numerous times as it grows. Using the `IEnumerable` results directly might show a greater difference.

Answer (score 11):

`OfType()` should be slower since doing safe type `is` check before an actual explicit cast operation, in the same time `Cast()` doing only explicit cast.

Theoretically `OfType` woudl be faster in case of many elements with "wrong type", so loop enumerates further just after `is` check, in case of `Cast()` on the same collection you would end's up with an `InvalidCastException` on each element of "wrong type" so this would be relatively slower.

**Source code extracted using ILSpy:**

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
private static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }

    foreach (object current in source)
    {
        // **Type check**
        if (current is TResult)
        {
            // **Explicit cast**
            yield return (TResult)current;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}

// System.Linq.Enumerable
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> enumerable = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        return enumerable;
    }
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }

    foreach (object current in source)
    {
        // **Explicit cast only**
        yield return (TResult)current;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just reverse the order of `OfType` and `Cast` in your method and you'll note that there is no difference. The first one always runs faster than the second one. **This is a case of a bad microbenchmark.**

Wrapping your code in a loop to run them in random order:

```
OfType: 1224
Cast: 2815
Cast: 2961
OfType: 3010
OfType: 3027
Cast: 2987
...
```

And then again:

```
Cast: 1207
OfType: 2781
Cast: 2930
OfType: 2964
OfType: 2964
OfType: 2987
...
```

Lifting out the `Regex.Matches`, which appears to cause the problem:

```
Cast: 1247
OfType: 210
OfType: 170
Cast: 171
...
```

and

```
OfType: 1225
Cast: 202
OfType: 171
Cast: 192
Cast: 415
```

So, no. `OfType` is not faster than `Cast`. And no, `Cast` is not faster than `OfType`.

Comment: Cast is MUCH, MUCH faster than OfType.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432268/2499090

Answer (score 1):

Actually isof() first checks the type and then casts it, where as cast() just does the 2nd part. So obviously isof() will be slower than direct casting

http://codenets.blogspot.in/2010/06/cast-vs-oftype.html