# Performance of OfType<> vs "is" queries

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In TPH inheritance, is there any difference between this:

```
context.Firms.OfType<RedFirm>()
```

and this:

```
context.Firms.Where(item => item is RedFirm);
```

In terms of performance?

Comment: If there is any difference in performance at all it doesn't come from different SQL which is exactly the same for both queries: `SELECT ... FROM [Firms] WHERE [Discriminator] = 'RedFirm'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OfType<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (Or an `IQueryable<T>`, etc). It internally does an `is` and casts those objects to only return those of type T. `OfType<TResult>` also includes a short-circuit check that if the entire `IEnumerable<T>` is castable to `IEnumerable<TResult>` then it will perform significantly faster since it will not check each individual item in the collection.

`Where` does not change the returned type of `IEnumerable<T>`, and since you will have to cast them (if needed), `OfType<T>` should be slightly faster since it includes this call.

Related links: [Why is OfType<> faster than Cast<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430570/why-is-oftype-faster-than-cast)

Comment: This is all about Enumerable queries, not about Entity Framework. None of this applies.

Comment: And EF doesn't matter in this case. No EF context has a translation for `is` or `OfType<T>` as far as I understand.

Comment: @MichaelDunlap, please edit your answer; I checked `System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<>` and it doesn't have that short-circuit check you mentioned (.NET 4.7.1).