# RegEx split not giving expected results

Tags: c#, regex, split

So I have a text file that is feeding me comma separated data that is enclosed in double quotes like so:

```
string test = "\"foo\",\"bar\",\"1\",\"\",\"baz\"";
```

I want to capture every value, originally I simply split on comma, but I noticed sometimes things had commas between the quotes, so I changed it to instead use a regex to just pull everything between quotes with a very simple regex:

```
string pattern = "\"[^\"]*\"";
```

Using regexpal this returns exactly what I want, but for whatever reason or another when I run this small program in c#, I get returned a list of all commas, instead of the values I'm actually interested in, I'm not really sure why.  Can anyone spot my error?

```
string test = "\"foo\",\"bar\",\"1\",\"\",\"baz\"";
string pattern = "\"[^\"]*\"";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(test, pattern); //Returns a list of commas in quotes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Regex.Split` uses the pattern to decide where the sequence must be split. In other words, the pattern describes *separators*, not the content that you would like to capture:

> Splits an input string into an array of substrings at the positions defined by a regular expression pattern

To use the expression the way you want you need to call `Regex.Matches` to obtain a [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx), and retrieve the individual matches from that collection:

```
string test = "\"foo\",\"bar\",\"1\",\"\",\"baz\"";
string pattern = "\"[^\"]*\"";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);
foreach (var m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/QNomKH).

Comment: Ah, I see that makes sense.  I suppose I actually want RegEx.Match or something else, or else refine my RegEx to actually use the delimiter and not what I want to match.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, got it working, also used this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416191/how-to-convert-matchcollection-to-string-array to convert the match collection back into a string array to just plug it straight into where my old naive split code was.  (Will accept when it lets me, thanks again!).