# Regex Matchcollection groups

Tags: c#, regex

I already tried two days to solve the Problem, that I have a MatchCollection. In the patter is a Group and I want to have a list with the Solutions of the Group (there were two or more Solutions).

```
string input = "<tr><td>Mi, 09.09.15</td><td>1</td><td>PK</td><td>E</td><td>123</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Mi, 09.09.15</td><td>2</td><td>ER</td><td>ER</td><td>234</td><td></td></tr>";
string Patter2 = "^<tr>$?<td>$?[D-M][i-r],[' '][0-3][1-9].[0-1][1-9].[0-9][0-9]$?</td>$?<td>$?([1-9][0-2]?)$?</td>$?";
Regex r2 = new Regex(Patter2);
MatchCollection mc2 = r2.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in mc2)
{
     GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
     string s = groups[1].Value;
     Datum2.Text = s;
}
```

But only the last match (2) appears in the TextBox "Datum2".
I know that I have to use e.g. a listbox, but the Groups[1].Value is a string...

Thanks for your help and time.
Dieter

Comment: you are replacing the Datum2 text field with s. It is not appending anything to Datum2.Text. If you want to see all matches you can say Datum2.Text = s + Datum2.Text

Comment: But Datum2 is an empty textbox.

Comment: Only the first match.

Comment: Did you consider using other tools than regex for parsing out data from HTML strings? Did you hear about HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: There is loop there around match collection. If you want to print all matches in the text box either convert the [match collection to string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416191/how-to-convert-matchcollection-to-string-array) or use Datum2.Text = s + Datum2.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to correct in the code is `Datum2.Text = s;` would overwrite the text in `Datum2` if it were more than one match.

Now, about your regex,

- `^` forces a match at the begging of the line, so there is really only 1 match. If you remove it, it'll match twice.
- I can't seem to understand what was intended with `$?` all over the pattern (just take them out).
- `[' ']` matches "either a quote, a space or a quote (no need to repeat characters in a character class.
- All dots in `[0-3][1-9].[0-1][1-9].[0-9][0-9]` need to be escaped. A dot matches any character otherwise.
- `[0-1][1-9]` matches all months except "10". The second character shoud be `[0-9]` (or `\d`).

**Code:**

```
string input = "<tr><td>Mi, 09.09.15</td><td>1</td><td>PK</td><td>E</td><td>123</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Mi, 09.09.15</td><td>2</td><td>ER</td><td>ER</td><td>234</td><td></td></tr>";
string Patter2 = "<tr><td>[D-M][i-r],[' ][0-3][0-9]\\.[0-1][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]</td><td>([1-9][0-2]?)</td>";
Regex r2 = new Regex(Patter2);
MatchCollection mc2 = r2.Matches(input);
string s= "";

foreach (Match match in mc2)
{
     GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
     s = s + " " + groups[1].Value;
}

Datum2.Text = s;
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LJIXJ10732)

---

You should know that regex is not the tool to parse HTML. It'll work for simple cases, but for real cases do consider using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)